# Safari does not remember Scroll-Position on "Back"-Button

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

we have some very strange issue in our webshop:

- You scroll down in a category and choose a product
- After the load of the productdetail page you go back with the "Back-Button" in Safari
- **Safari does not remember the scroll position and automatically scrolls up to the header.** (You can see for less then a second the right scroll-position before safari starts scrolling up to the header)

And now here it gets really strange:

- This problem just exists if the "Google Analytics JavaScript" ist loading!
- If we reject the cookie for Google Analytics, the problem is not happening. (As I can see from the Safari-Console, the JavaScript of "Analytics.js" ist loading at last)

Do you have any ideas how we can prevent safari from scrolling up to the header after clicking the "Back-Button"?

Do you have any idea how I can debug this issue?

Best regards.

Comment: hi @Datastorm1989.. can you tell us how the scripts are implemented..? are you using Cookiebot solution for cookies..? if yes - how it has been added..? Are there some JS errors in the console..?

Comment: @marioBoss Its added by JavaScript. There are no JavaScript-Errors. Tracking works fine. If we deactivate the tracking by decline the cookies the "Back-Button" goes back to the right Scroll-Position.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the accessibility settings. Go to system settings, accessibility, keyboard, and turn off "full keyboard access."